# Windows cut off at the bottom of screen in overview

Tags: gnome-shell, activities-overview

When I enter the window overview by pressing the <kbd>super</kbd> key, I keep having windows on the bottom row of the overview cut off at the bottom edge of the screen, like the overview is reaching past the screen. It's only the windows that do this, the dock and the desktop list do not. I've tried this on multiple screens, and also tried it while having a single-monitor setup or multi-monitor set up, and the problem is consistent.

[image: Here is an example of the behavior I'm describing.]

Comment: Hi also mention your Ubuntu version along with GNOME which you already mentioned.